# Custom Keras Layers fail

Tags: keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I want custom Keras layer, realize the output of the two models assign different weights and the weight can be trained as the following

```
prediction1=model1.output
prediction2=model2.output
class WeightedSum(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(WeightedSum, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.weights =K.variable(np.random.random(1))
        self.trainable_weights=[self.weights]
    def call(self, two_model_outputs):
        return self.weights * two_model_outputs[0] + (1 - self.weights) * two_model_outputs[1]
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
final_pred=WeightedSum()([prediction1,prediction2])
```

[image: model]

[image: mthod]

but I made a mistake in writing and don't know how to do it.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test-paper3.py", line 182, in <module>
        final_pred=WeightedSum()([prediction1,prediction2])
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 431, in __call__
        self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
      File "test-paper3.py", line 162, in build
        self.weights =K.variable(np.random.random(1))
    AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: So, what is wrong? What's the error? Where?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-paper3.py", line 182, in <module>
    final_pred=WeightedSum()([prediction1,prediction2])
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 431, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "test-paper3.py", line 162, in build
    self.weights =K.variable(np.random.random(1))
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Keras is protecting itself from letting you use a word it considers reserved somehow?

Try to add the weights in a standard way and use another variable name:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(1,),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  #I suggest a constraint here, see below
                                  trainable=True)

    #this works as an initializer for the weights
    K.set_value(self.kernel, np.array([0.5])) 
        #you can use np.random here, but it seems safer to go with 0.5

    #this tells keras that the layer is build in fact
    super(WeightedSum, self).build(shapes)
```

Of course you will need to replace `weights` with `kernel` in the `call` method.

---

**Non related:**

I suggest you also use a constraint to keep the kernel within 0 and 1.

```
from keras.constraints import MinMaxNorm


........
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(1,),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  constraint = MinMaxNorm(0,1)
                                  trainable=True)
........
```